# sqllite where clause always return empty

Tags: android, sqlite, where-clause

I am selecting row based on user id but non is returning
select all is working and i am sure of the id in the where
can somone help me what is wrong with the query

```
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_Txns
            + " WHERE " + COLUMN_USERID + "  = ?";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    List<TransactionModel> savedTransactions = new ArrayList<>();

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null
            , new String[]{getLogin_id()});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `rawQuery()` this way:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, new String[]{getLogin_id()});
```

The 2nd parameter is the selection arguments. 
The signature you used with 3 parameters is this:

```
rawQuery(String sql, String[] selectionArgs, CancellationSignal cancellationSignal)
```

and you don't need that.

Comment: still same issue
is the sql  query correct?
maybe something wrong with the structure ?

Comment: If the app does not crash then the sql statement is valid. You must debug and check the value returned by `getLogin_id()` if it **really exists** in the table.